# Kickstart Red Hat 5.x

Tags: redhat, kickstart

I am having a little issue with the `ks.cfg` file;

1. I read a post that said I should copy it into the `isolinux` folder but it is write-protected. What do I do?
2. Secondly, I read another post that makes it a little easier; `cp ks.cfg ~/bootdisk/RHEL/` , but when I converted it to an ISO file and ran the `linux ks=/ks.cfg` command it didn't work.
3. Is the `ks.cfg` file supposed to be in the ISO file that was converted?

Answer (score 2):

First, is the `ks.cfg` file valid?  Run `ksvalidator` to check for mistakes in syntax/formatting.

If you are modifying the boot media to include your own custom Kickstart, you'll need to copy the contents of the media to local disk to make your changes.  It sounds like you are trying to copy your script to non-writable media such as a CD-R/RW.  Otherwise, it's as simple as making the existing ks.cfg writable on disk. (`chmod ug+w ks.cfg`)

Here are my complete notes on customizing boot media. (I start with an ISO I've downloaded from Red Hat instead of existing media.)

1. Copy vendor media to disk.

   `mkdir /tmp/bootiso`
   `mount -o loop /path/to/boot.iso /tmp/bootiso`
   `mkdir /tmp/bootisoks`
   `cp -r /tmp/bootiso/* /tmp/bootisoks/.`
   `umount /tmp/bootiso`
   `rmdir /tmp/bootiso`
2. Make ks.cfg writable and overwrite the vendor provided.

   `chmod ug+w /tmp/bootisoks/isolinux/ks.cfg`
   `mv /path/from/ks.cfg /tmp/bootisoks/isolinux/ks.cfg`
3. Make new ISO from source.

   `cd /tmp/bootisoks`
   `mkisofs -o /path/to/modified.iso -b isolinux.bin -c boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T isolinux/`

Then, you can burn the new ISO to disc and test a Kickstart!

Answer (score 0):

Please try my answer below.

1.ks.cfg can be located anywhere since the `ks=/dir/ofks.cfg/` option specific the right folder where `ks.cfg` is. If you don't use this option ,default searching path is / of your source installation.

2 & 3. Is the ks.cfg file supposed to be in the ISO file that was converted?

- Yes . If you burn your iso and install via cd/dvd. you can put ks.cfg into iso file , boot parameter for ks.cfg must be `"ks=cdrom:/ks.cfg"`
- No. If you won't burn your whole iso to cdrom. Or you manual mount iso after stage2 is running. Put the ks.cfg outside the iso.

Hope this help.